# Passing data to express backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm adding a stripe checkout to my website with this code in my react front end

```
    const response = await fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
       method: 'POST',
       });

    const session = await response.json();

    // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect them to Checkout.
    const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: session.id,
    });
```

and this one on my express server :

```
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ["BE", "FR", "DE", "CH"],
    },
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: "usd",
          product_data: {
            name: "T-shirt",
          },
          unit_amount: 10 * 100,
        },
        description: "Product 1",
        quantity: 1,
      },
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: "usd",
          product_data: {
            name: "Tsklip",
          },
          unit_amount: 2000,
        },
        description: "Product 2",
        quantity: 2,
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: "https://localhost:3000",
    cancel_url: "https://localhost:3000/cart",
  });

  res.json({ id: session.id });
});
```

I'd like to pass from my frontend to my backend some info.
How could I do that ? Is it possible with this code ?
Thanks !

Comment: You likely want to use the [`body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body) object of the Fetch API. There's a sample here: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/fetch-api/fetch-post.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data to body, then you can access them in express from `req.body`

```
const response = await fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify({ info: 'my info message', id: 1})
});
```

Also you should use
[body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) middleware to parse incoming request body

Comment: feel free to upvote and accept answer with check button